# problem with variable scope

Tags: php, mysql, oop

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Falco System');
$pdf->SetTitle('Llogaria');
$pdf->SetSubject('Llogaria');

// set default header data
//$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE , PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
//$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
//$image = $pdf->Image("tcpdf/images/logo.png", 15, 10, 60, 15, 'PNG', '', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
global $db;
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY date DESC limit 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$emri = $row['name'];
$html = <<<EOF
<!-- EXAMPLE OF CSS STYLE -->
<style>

    h1 {
        color: navy;
        font-family: times;
        font-size: 24pt;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    p.first {
        color: #003300;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    p.first span {
        color: #006600;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    p#second {
        color:#000;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 8pt;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    p#falemenderim {
        color:#000;
        font-family: times;
        font-size: 12pt;
        text-align: justify;
    }

    p#second > span {
        background-color: #FFFFAA;
    }
    table.first {
        color: #003300;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 8pt;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    td {
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;  
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    div.test {
        color: #CC0000;
        background-color: #FFFF66;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border-style: solid solid solid solid;
        border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border-color: green #FF00FF blue red;
        text-align: center;
    }
    td.Addressa {
        border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
        text-align:right;
    }
    td.logo {
        border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    }
    .bolder {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .hide {
    border-left:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    }
    .kuq {
    background-color: red;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    }
</style>

<br/><br/>
<table class="thise" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td height="50" class="logo">$image</td>
    <td class="Addressa">
        Falco system<br/>
        123 Rruga<br/>
        Tetove, MKD<br/>
        000 - 000 000<br/>
        email@firma.com
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


<br />

<table class="first" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="bolder">
    <td class="kuq">Pasagjeri</td>
    <td class="kuq">Prej</td>
    <td class="kuq">Deri</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>$emri Islami</td>
    <td>Tetove</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" >

<tr>
    <td class="hide" width="345"></td>
    <td class="bolder" width="80">&Ccedil;mimi</td>
    <td >$ 100.00</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id="falemenderim">
    Ju falemenderojme qe keni zgjedhur te udhetoni me agjensionin tone, ju deshirojme nje rruge te mbare!
</p>

<p id="second">
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porta nisl at dui semper ut semper lectus volutpat. 
Integer sollicitudin cursus mi et fermentum. Pellentesque in sem id felis commodo auctor. Nulla fringilla dui ac odio
 iaculis vel posuere eros dignissim. Donec nulla odio, pretium vitae consectetur sit amet, hendrerit interdum mauris.<br/> 
- Proin tincidunt consectetur nisi vel pellentesque. Ut ac felis quis lorem porttitor convallis at in diam. Sed molestie, 
 sem at molestie posuere, nibh justo auctor nunc, eu posuere sem purus eget ipsum. In auctor gravida vulputate. Aenean in<br/> 
- sapien purus, non ornare tortor. Cras nec risus lacus. Integer dictum sodales bibendum. 
</p>
EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('tiketa.pdf', 'I');
require_once ('classes/class.db.php');
$db = new MySQL(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, false);

?>
```

This gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   query() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\falco\GeneratePDF.php
>   on line 64

I have tried to make the $db variable global, when I initiate and require the db class which connects to the DB in the top of  the script then I get another error! I dont know what to do to make this work!

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$db` declaration is all the way at the bottom. Put it at the top instead and get rid of the `global $db` since I don't see this as a function call.

Comment: the problem is that when I declare it in the top then I get another error telling me that headers have already been sent to the browser!

Comment: @TooCool Can you provide properly indented and clean code? It's extremely difficult to tell what's going on...

Comment: yes I am going to remove some of code that is not useful, but if you want to see the whole project you can see it here:
https://github.com/toocool/Falco

Comment: I ended up just pulling the github raw and using that, since the `>>>`'s before the code were just hard to read. You may have to redo changes. Anyhow, can you put the `$db` declaration in the bottom at the top and show the full error and 15 lines before + 15 lines after the line it says the error is at?

Comment: Here is the error:


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\falco\classes\class.db.php:978) in C:\xampp\htdocs\falco\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 8208
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Comment: Ok i fixed it now, well not really me.. it just started to work! I think the problem was with the chace! any way thank you for your time and help